# CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down in redis

Tags: caching, redis

I am running 6 redis nodes  ,3 masters and 3 slaves , every master has 1 slave .

```
Master[0] -> Slots 0 - 5460

Master[1] -> Slots 5461 - 10922

Master[2] -> Slots 10923 - 16383

Adding replica 172.17.0.5:6382 to 172.17.0.2:6379

Adding replica 172.17.0.6:6383 to 172.17.0.3:6380

Adding replica 172.17.0.7:6384 to 172.17.0.4:6381
```

The clustering is running and I can SET and GET Keys.

I shutdown master1 172.17.0.2:6379 , slave1 (172.17.0.5:6382)  has became master ,cluster is still running  .

I shutdown slave1 (172.17.0.5:6382) , I tried to SET keys I have got this error

> (error) CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down

What I expected when I shutdown master1 and slave1 , cluster will still running and accepts redis operations but the opposite has happened.

What is  the reason behind this ?

Is it applicable to solve this problem without starting master1 or slave1 again ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because some slots are stored in master1 and slave1, if both of them are down, these slots will no longer been covered by any node in the cluster. When this happens, by default, the cluster is down. You can modify the behavior by changing the `cluster-require-full-coverage` option.

Quote from `redis.conf`:

> By default Redis Cluster nodes stop accepting queries if they detect
>   there is at least an hash slot uncovered (no available node is serving
>   it). This way if the cluster is partially down (for example a range of
>   hash slots are no longer covered) all the cluster becomes, eventually,
>   unavailable. It automatically returns available as soon as all the
>   slots are covered again.
>
> However sometimes you want the subset of the cluster which is working,
>   to continue to accept queries for the part of the key space that is
>   still covered. In order to do so, just set the
>   cluster-require-full-coverage option to no.
>
> cluster-require-full-coverage yes

**UPDATE**:

In order to ensure all slots are covered, normally, you can set up a cluster with `N` masters and `N + 1` slaves. Then assign a slave for each master, i.e. `N -> N`. The extra slave can replicate data from a random master. When one of you master is down, the corresponding slave will become the new master. Then you can make the extra slave to replicate data from the new master.

In a word, you must ensure each master has at least one slave at any time.

Comment: Thank you very much @for_stack , regarding  covering slots , I think we will add new node as master and assign slots to it , but it takes time to recover , may affect clients who read keys  from this master .

Comment: Normally you can set up a cluster with `N` master and `N + 1` slaves. Check my update for the answer.

Comment: OK @for_stack , in the first time when  one master fails the extra slave will become master then we haven't extra slave , if any master fails again we will return to the previous state .